# VPS Discord.js Music Bot 410 Error

Tags: nodejs, vps, music-player

i trying download youtube video and i getting error 410 have someone idea how to fix that i using version 20.04

for downloading i using nodes

code:

```
    const fs = require('fs'); 
    const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
    
    const stream = ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVdEvxUlU0s', { filter: 'audioonly' }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('video.mp3'));
    
    console.log('Starting Download');
    
    stream.on('data', chunk => {
      console.log('downloaded', chunk.length);
    });
    
    stream.on('error', err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
    
    stream.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Finished');
    });
```

Log:

```
Starting Download
/root/youtube/node_modules/miniget/dist/index.js:206
                let err = new Miniget.MinigetError(`Status code: ${res.statusCode}`, res.statusCode);
                          ^

MinigetError: Status code: 410
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/root/youtube/node_modules/miniget/dist/index.js:206:27)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:701:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:542:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
Emitted 'error' event on PassThrough instance at:
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  statusCode: 410
}

Node.js v18.15.0
```

Comment: Did you look up HTTP 410 error?  An educated guess is they are blocking your download.

Comment: yes and i didint find nothing maybe i will tried request for change location or IP or i dont know

Comment: HTTP 410 means "Gone" - to be interpreted as "The target resource you're fetching used to exist here, but is no longer here, and this is a permanent condition",  Mozilla describes it as: "The HTTP 410 Gone client error response code indicates that access to the target resource is no longer available at the origin server and that this condition is likely to be permanent." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410). I would suggest that whatever tool you're using to pull data from YouTube is busted, and you need to talk to the developer of the tool (MiniGet it seems) for help

Comment: You may find the info on this site interesting. https://multimedia.easeus.com/video-download/cant-download-youtube-videos.html#:~:text=According%20to%20YouTube's%20Terms%20and,the%20more%20ads%20they%20see.